# Is there anyway to have DHT22 data in real time?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, sensors

First of all, I'm using a Raspberry pi 3B+ and i followed the instructions of [this site](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-humidity-sensor-dht22/)

I got the code running and working fine, but the issue is that the data of the DHT22 is sent in a range of 3-10 second and i would like it to run each second (just like a arduino). Also i tried to send data from a Arduino to the Raspberry and it kept the same speed or even worse

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is your _programming_ question?

Comment: Well, i´m using Adafruit library, i didn't find any other library so maybe the result could change, and as i mentioned there is a webpage which i followed all the steps to do it